# Why does keyup event has different key property for same input?

Tags: javascript, html, keypress, keyup

I need to detect when input value changes and if the last character entered is '@' I need to edit this input in some way.

So I added event listener for `keyup` event.

```
const inputEl = document.getElementById('input');

inputEl.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    console.log(event.key);
})
```

This will sometimes log 'Shift' and '@' and sometimes 'Shift' and '2' for the same value entered (@)

[image]

If I add this listener to `keypress` event instead, it always logs 'Shift' and then '@'.

But I cannot use `keypress` because this event fires before `keyup` and before input value is updated in the DOM.

Is there a way to detect last entered character in a reliable way?

Answer (score 1):

You want to know *"if the last character entered is '@'"* so I would not use `event.key` for that as long as it triggers every key you press on your keyboard while you are focused in the input.

You should work with `event.target.value` and split the last character. Something like this:

```js
const inputEl = document.getElementById('input');

inputEl.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value.substr(value.length - 1)); 
})
```

```html
<input id="input"/>
```

Just note that it will fire listener with **every key you press** even if it won't write anything (like *shift*).